# In Heroku, why am I recieving an SSL error when trying to set environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to set up environment variables for a tiny Rails app that I've already deployed to Heroku.

When I run the command `heroku config:add VARIABLENAME=somevalue` I end up getting an error:

```
Setting config vars and restarting whispering-lake-xxx... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error: hostname was not match with the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
```

This is my first time trying to put something up on Heroku, so I don't know if there was some sort of SSL setup I'm supposed to do beforehand, or how to debug this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your command should work, I just ran it with an app of my own. If the error still persists in like an hour you should maybe contact heroku support.

Comment: Beforehand, do you use the latest `heroku` gem or the heroku toolkit? If it's the gem, try updating it with `gem update heroku`. If it's the heroku toolkit, download and install the latest version.